# How to get Youcompleteme to work with Vimscript?

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript, autocompletion, plugin-you-complete-me, plugin-neocomplete

I've switched from NeoComplete to YouCompleteMe because it has much better intellisense, though I had NeoComplete working much better with Omnicompletion.

NeoComplete was able to automatically provide a popup with the right completions without me having to enter a specific mapping (`<C-x><C-v>` for Vim commands, `<C-x><C-d>` for directories, etc.). If I typed `colorscheme` for example, it would provide completions for all my schemes.

How can I get YouCompleteMe to do the same? At the moment, it overrides the `<C-x><C-u>` command, but if I want Vimscript or directory completion I have to enter the default key bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ycm can cooperate with [Shougo/neco-vim](https://github.com/Shougo/neco-vim)

```
autocmd FileType vim setlocal omnifunc=te#complete#vim_complete


function! te#complete#vim_complete( findstart, base ) abort
   let line_prefix = s:get_input()
   if a:findstart
   let ret = necovim#get_complete_position( line_prefix )
   if ret < 0
    return col( '.' ) " default to current
  endif
   return ret
  else
   return necovim#gather_candidates( line_prefix . a:base, a:base )
  endif
 endfunction
```

My vim config: [t-vim](https://github.com/tracyone/t-vim)

Answer (score 3):

Based on tracyone's vim configuration I have created a fork of [necovim](https://github.com/IngoHeimbach/neco-vim) that automatically registers as vim omnifunc. Just add the plugin with your favorite vim plugin manager and it will work out of the box with YouCompleteMe.